# Sorted list of files in a particular folder

Tags: java, file, recursion, comparator

I have written a piece of code where I intend to get the list of all files(.txt, jpg, .png, .pdf) excluding directory name. Infact the code is supposed to crawl inside each directory and give the file name. I want the files to be listed in a sorted manner.

```
class CompareFiles implements Comparator<File>{

    @Override
    public int compare(File arg0, File arg1) {
        return arg0.getName().compareTo(arg1.getName());
    }

}
```

Class using it:

```
public class DirectoryRecursion {

    public static void check(String path) {
        File list = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFile = list.listFiles();
        ArrayList<File> asf = new ArrayList<File>();
        for(File file: listOfFile){
            if(file.isDirectory())
                check(file.getAbsolutePath());
            else                {
                asf.add(file);                  
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Before: ");
        for(File file: asf)
            System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());

        Collections.sort(asf, new CompareFiles());
        System.out.println("Before: ");
        for(File file: asf)
            System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());          
    } 
}
```

But unfortunately the output for both “Before” and “after” is similar.

Comment: could you share a sample expected and actual output you're getting and the input provided.

Comment: Other than your System.out.println( ) for the after the sorting - which should say System.out.println("After: ") - instead of "Before", this should work...

Comment: oops the second before is supposed to be "After", yet my code is not working as required.

Comment: Before: 
File: e.bmp
File: f.bmp
After: 
File: e.bmp
File: f.bmp
Before: 
File: a.txt
File: c.txt
After: 
File: a.txt
File: c.txt
Before: 
After: 
Before: 
File: a.bmp
File: a.JPG
File: b.txt
File: c.bmp
File: d.txt
After: 
File: a.JPG
File: a.bmp
File: b.txt
File: c.bmp
File: d.txt
Something like this. very messy.

Comment: @Shailja add the sample to the question itself and not the comments.

Comment: So, it is working fine. The files are being sorted lexicographically. What else do you expect? See the last example where a.JPG, which is after a.bmp, goes before because J is before b in the lexiscographic order.

Comment: It works fine. May be you need to move sort outside check method and sort after collecting all files into one list?

Comment: @Syroezhkin cool. I got your point. I can see my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Sample output seems just fine in terms of sorting it based on the custom comparator `CompareFiles`:

> ```
> Before: File: a.bmp File: a.JPG File: b.txt File: c.bmp File: d.txt 
> After: File: a.JPG File: a.bmp File: b.txt File: c.bmp File: d.txt
> ```

Just to prove it the String **`a.JPG`** is [*lexicographically greater than the string argument*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) **`a.bmp`**

Comment: To avoid this behaviour you can use compareToIgnoreCase method instead of compareTo

Comment: @Syroezhkin I strongly believe, thats not what the OP intends.